# Unable to order by translated column in Rails using Mobility

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobility

*This question is based on an [issue](https://github.com/shioyama/mobility/issues/169) posted to the Mobility GitHub project.*

### Context

- **Rails**: 5.0.6
- **Mobility**: 0.4.2 (with table backend)

I'm working with an articles table that supports multiple article types (e.g., blog post, case study, knowledge base article). This table includes a column to track the number of times an article is viewed—an integer column that increments every time a `show` action is called for an article.

In implementing translations for these articles, I want to track the number of views *for each translation individually*, not for the main article object. In an effort to achieve this, I included the `views` property as one of the translated properties on my object:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  include Taggable
  include PgSearch

  translates :title, type: :string
  translates :subtitle, type: :text
  translates :body, type: :text
  translates :views, type: :integer

  multisearchable :against => [:title, :subtitle, :body]

  has_and_belongs_to_many :products

  attachment :hero_image, content_type: %w(image/jpeg image/png image/gif)

  validates :title, :body, :posted_on, presence: true

  scope :current, -> { where 'posted_on < ?', Date.tomorrow }
  scope :news_articles, -> { where type: ['BlogPost', 'CaseStudy'] }

  def log_view(by = 1)
    self.views ||= 0
    self.views += by
    self.save(touch: false)
  end

  def to_param
    "#{id} #{title}".parameterize
  end

  def published?
    posted_on < Date.tomorrow
  end
end
```

### Expected Behavior

In my controller, I want to list the top ten most viewed articles, which I get with this query:

```
@top_articles = Article.current.news_articles.order(views: :desc, posted_on: :desc).limit(10)
```

I expect to receive an array of articles, as I did before implementing Mobility.

### Actual Behavior

What I get instead is `#<Article::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x233686c>`. If I then try to convert that to an array with `@top_articles.to_a`, I get this error:

```
  Article Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE (posted_on < '2018-02-11') AND "articles"."type" IN ('BlogPost', 'CaseStudy') ORDER BY "articles"."views" DESC, "articles"."posted_on" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 10]]
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column articles.views does not exist
LINE 1: ...les"."type" IN ('BlogPost', 'CaseStudy') ORDER BY "articles"...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE (posted_on < '2018-02-11') AND "articles"."type" IN ('BlogPost', 'CaseStudy') ORDER BY "articles"."views" DESC, "articles"."posted_on" DESC LIMIT $1
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:598:in `async_exec'
```

Changing the query to include `i18n`:

```
@top_articles = Article.i18n.current.news_articles.order(views: :desc, posted_on: :desc).limit(10)
```

… returns `#<#<Mobility::Backends::ActiveRecord::Table::QueryMethods:0x00000000050a86d8>:0x286c3e0>`, and when I try to convert that to an array, I get the same thing:

```
  Article Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE (posted_on < '2018-02-11') AND "articles"."type" IN ('BlogPost', 'CaseStudy') ORDER BY "articles"."views" DESC, "articles"."posted_on" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 10]]
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column articles.views does not exist
LINE 1: ...les"."type" IN ('BlogPost', 'CaseStudy') ORDER BY "articles"...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE (posted_on < '2018-02-11') AND "articles"."type" IN ('BlogPost', 'CaseStudy') ORDER BY "articles"."views" DESC, "articles"."posted_on" DESC LIMIT $1
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:598:in `async_exec'
```

It turns out that while Mobility supports the use of translated fields in the `where` clause, it does not currently support them in the `order` clause of an Active Record query.

### Workaround attempts

#### 1. Reference the translation table in the `order` clause

Based on feedback from the gem author, I tried the query:

```
Article.i18n.current.news_articles.order('article_translations.views desc', 'articles.posted_on desc')
```

… which returns a `#<#<Mobility::Backends::ActiveRecord::Table::QueryMethods>>` object, and `to_a` returns this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "article_translations"
LINE 1: ...les"."type" IN ('BlogPost', 'CaseStudy') ORDER BY article_tr...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE (posted_on < '2018-02-12') AND "articles"."type" IN ('BlogPost', 'CaseStudy') ORDER BY article_translations.views desc, articles.posted_on desc LIMIT $1
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:598:in `async_exec'
```

#### 2. Add a `joins` or `includes` clause for the translation table

```
Article.i18n.joins(:article_translations).order('article_translations.views desc', 'articles.posted_on desc').limit(10)
```

This query, again, returns a `#<#<Mobility::Backends::ActiveRecord::Table::QueryMethods>>` object, and `to_a` results in:

```
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Can't join 'Article' to association named 'article_translations'; perhaps you misspelled it?
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:231:in `find_reflection'
```

#### 3. Add `has_many :article_translations` to model

Adding a relation to the model throws back this error:

```
uninitialized constant Article::ArticleTranslation
```

### So…

What should I try next?

Comment: can u post your db schema? is there a views column in there in your articles table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*UPDATE*

Ordering by translated attributes is now supported as of version 0.8.0/

Just do this:

```
Article.i18n.current.news_articles.
  order(:views => :desc, :'articles.posted_on' => :desc)
```

and Mobility will handle everything (you don't need to join the translation table, etc.)

*ORIGINAL ANSWER*

You were right that you need to join the translations table, but the association is named `translations`, not `article_translations`.

In any case, there is a method `join_translations` that joins the translation table, so this should work:

```
Article.i18n.
  current.
  news_articles.
  join_translations.
  order('article_translations.views desc', 'articles.posted_on desc')
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks for the prompt response. 

Comment: I assume this holds true for working with other AR clauses, like `select`?

Comment: Yes, `article_translations.views` is the actual table/column so should work normally with any AR methods.